# When does a set of functions contain a normal family

Tags: complex-analysis

For what set $\Omega$ is the family of functions $F_{\Omega}=\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{f:f(z)=z^{n},z \in \Omega\}$ normal?
A family $F$ is said to be normal in $n$ if every sequence $\{f_{n}\}$
of functions in $F$ contains a subsequence which converges uniformly on every
compact subset of $n$. I know that inside the unit disk $z^{n}$ converges uniformly to zero but what about $|z|\geq 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\Omega$ is the complement of the unit circle.

Indeed, on $\{ |z|>1\}$, the sequence $\{z \mapsto z^n \}$ converges locally uniformly to $\infty$ (I don't know about your conventions, but usually this is included in the definition of normal family).

Also, if $U$ is some open set intersecting the unit circle, then no sequence $\{ z \mapsto z^{n_k} : \lim n_k = +\infty\}$ can be locally uniformly convergent on $U$, since part of it will converge to $0$ and part will converge to $\infty$.

You can also have a look at the notion of Fatou set, and check that the Fatou set of $z \mapsto z^d$ is exactly $\Omega$, by basically the same arguments.